# IF statement in a do_shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, shortcode

Is it possible to do a if statement in a do_shortcode?

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[table width='500'] " . 
        if ( have_posts() ) : 
            while ( have_posts() ) : 
                the_post(); 
                the_content(); 
            endwhile; 
        endif; . 
    "[/table]"); 
?>
```

It gives me an unexpected T_IF.

EDIT: And without the IF statement it gives the post outside the shortcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `echo do_shortcode()` is a function call. You can not pass a conditional statement as an [argument of a function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php). What you need to do is pass in the returned result of your query as an argument of the function;

```
//assuming you have taken care of your query prior to this point
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $content = get_the_content(); //store content in variable

    echo do_shortcode("[table width='500'] ". $content . "[/table]"); 

endwhile; endif;
```

Note:

In the example above, to prevent your content being echoed immediately you must call `get_the_content()` which `returns` its value as opposed to `the_content()` which immediately echo's the content. That is why your content appears outside of the shortcode when run without the incorrect conditional statement passed as an argument.

### Extended answer:

In light of your additional comment and extended question, to check for the existence of some "thing" or that some "thing" meets a particular condition you would conduct your testing outside of the function call to your shortcode much in the same way as we have done above;

```
//assuming you have taken care of your query prior to this point
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $content = get_the_content(); //store content in variable
    
    $thing = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'thing', true );

    if ($thing === "yes") {
       
       //assuming you want to concatenate your content with an image
       $content = $content . '<br> <img src="path_to_image" />';

    } 

    echo do_shortcode("[table width='500'] ". $content . "[/table]"); 

endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew this, but just forgot it.

Comment: How do I check if an argument is equal to something inside the do_shortcode? Like: 'if $thing == yes { echo 'blabla '}'?

Comment: What is `$thing` supposed to equal and what are you checking that should be equal to `$thing`?

Comment: It's for a custom post type display, now it's displaying yes/no with: "esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'thing', true ) )" inside the do_shortcode. But it want to give it a image with a check or cross instead of the text yes/no.

Comment: ...additional information provided above.